# How to secure communication between Laravel and Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

Laravel backend will be accessing to Lumen via API using Guzzle.

I don't need a database in Lumen, so how can I add security between Laravel and Lumen? As far I am aware if I need pass token I would database access in Lumen.

Lumen is for internal use, which is not for the public to access.

Comment: so Lumen is your frontend and Laravel your backend? or are they completely separate APIs?

Comment: Laravel for frontend+backend (admin panel) and Lumen for API for other purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

- Store a key in your `.env` of your laravel installation, call it `LUMEN_API_TOKEN`
- Do the same on the Lumen side
- Create the API endpoint on the Lumen side, as explained in its documentation
- Use Token authentication, to authenticate any client connecting to the Lumen Endpoint(s). The key provided by the connector, needs to be equal to `LUMEN_API_TOKEN`
- for token authentication you can use a header key, or simply a GET-Parameter...something like http://your_Lumen_site/endpoint?token=12345
- Use Guzzle on Laravel to connect to Lumen

Comment: That is good suggestion. If I decided to go with a header key - I am assuming I need to create a middleware in Lumen to validate the token on the header for every request?

Comment: Will there be many users? Then I would go for the JWT solution. Otherwise I would keep it simple, handle it all quickly in the controller action (or middleware if you want to cleaner)....But always use HTTPS.

Comment: I am hoping to have thousands of users. User will typically login to admin panel - I will required User and Password using Laravel Auth (session). And then Controllers will make calls to Lumen using Guzzle. Would JWT still be better for that?

Comment: From what I understand the connection between Laravel and Lumen is internal. So you need no JWT for that.....Just prepare some fixed shared keys with a HTTPS connection is explained simply in my answer......

Answer (score 1):

You can create JWT keys on your Laravel application and authenticate it on the Lumen application. The Lumen application just needs the key to decrypt and validate the token. No database needed.

I would recommend this [JWT Library](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) which plays well with Laravel and Lumen

Comment: Hmm. Do I need to install JWT package on Laravel only or both? How can Lumen decrypt the key if JWT package on Laravel.